# Anonymous function on JS

Tags: javascript

Alert: JavaScript beginner here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function mostraralerta() {
            alert("you've clicked!");
        }
        function hacerclic() {
            document.getElementById("boton").onClick = function(){
            mostraralerta();
            };
        }
        window.onLoad=hacerclic();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="boton" value="click">
    </body>
</html>
```

When you click on the input it doesn't shows the alert. If I remove the anonymous function and do it directly:

```
document.getElementById("boton").onClick = mostraralerta();
```

or with another selector:

```
document.querySelector("#boton").onClick = mostraralerta();
```

It shows the alert as soon as you open the webpage, instead of when clicking the button.

Also I have tried with another html tag instead of an input, but the only way I have made this code to works is to put directly the event onClick on the input, but I'd like to know how to make it works with the functions and onload.

Comment: `document.getElementById("boton")` return undefined here since your button is not yet in the DOM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By including the brackets at the end of `mostraralerta` you're executing that function and storing the result of it in `.onclick` What you want to do is pass the name of the function without executing it, like this:

```
document.getElementById("boton").onclick = mostraralerta;
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("boton")` is null when the `hacerclic` function is called.This is because the input tag is not rendered.You can fix it by moving the window.onload to the end like this

```
<body>
    <input type="button" id="boton" value="click">
    <script>window.onload= hacerclic();</script>
</body>
```

And the onclick is all lower case:

```
 document.getElementById("boton").onclick = function(){
 mostraralerta()
 }
```